# sub-category showing up in wrong order in breadcrumbs

Tags: categories

On my site nwtraveler.com when I create a new post with the primary category of "Oregon" and sub-category as "Southern" it lists them in wrong order in breadcrumbs... All the other sub-categories show up correctly such as " Central / Oregon " and "Willamette Valley / Oregon" but whenever I choose sub-category of "Southern" it shows up in breadcrumbs in wrong/reverse order as "Oregon / Southern" ... seems to be some kind of bug in category hierarchy for this one sub-category ... any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you've a category (parent one) named as Oregon and its sub-category 'Southern', therefore, Oregon / Southern is the correct output.

It seems others are in wrong order. If Oregon is parent for Willamette Valley and Central then the result should be:

- Oregon / Central
- Oregon / Willamette Valley

Consider what hierarchy you exactly have in the backend vs. what you exactly need.